# Authentication Failure: AADSTS50005 while downloading files from sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, shareplum

My requirement is to download single or multiple files from a folder in sharepoint.
I have tried using [shareplum](https://github.com/iamlu-coding/python-download-sharepoint-file/) and [sharepy](https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy).

Both are giving the below error:

> Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', "AADSTS50005: User tried to log in to a device from a platform (Unknown) that's currently not supported through Conditional Access policy. Supported device platforms are: iOS, Android, Mac, and Windows flavors."

I am using a windows machine still getting the error.
Kindly help in resolving the issue or is there any other way to download the files from sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new policy that allow user to gone past conditional access policy in your office 365/ SP online.

Please follow the given below URL and if you are still facing an issue can reach out to me.

I have develop a code using Python and C# that allow user to upload and download file using Shareplum from Share point site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/646771/34access-has-been-blocked-by-conditional-access-po.html